# Extra yticks interfering with label distances

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks

I have a series of graphs with similar formatting, but I'm finding some of the labels are positioned too far from the axis numbers, as shown in the screenshots below.

[image: label bug]

The below code reproduces the problem. If you comment out the `extra y ticks` line, the issue is corrected, which suggests these are somehow interfering in the calculation used to determine the correct position for the labels.

How can I get the labels to all be placed at the same distance from the axis? It should all look like the image on the right, regardless of whether the extra ticks are present or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Absorption Energy ($cm^{-1}$)},
    ylabel={Fluorescence Energy ($cm^{-1}$)},
    xtick distance=5,ytick distance=10,minor y tick num=9,
    extra y ticks={37425,37435,37445,37455,37465,37475,37485,37495,37505,37515,37525},
    extra tick style={major tick length=0.15cm, xticklabels={}, yticklabels={}},
    width=12.5cm,height=9.45817cm,
    scale only axis=true,font=\footnotesize,enlargelimits=false,axis on top,xtick pos=left,ytick pos=left,tick align=outside,major tick length=0.2cm,tick style={black},scaled ticks=false,/pgf/number format/.cd,  1000 sep={\thinspace},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel},
    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ]

    \addplot graphics[xmin=37537.2353, xmax=37566.88252, ymin=37424.51271, ymax=37526.87033, includegraphics={keepaspectratio}] {example-image};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does my answer answer your question or do you need further assistance?

Comment: I'm still working on implementing it. As soon as I'm done I promise you'll be the first to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indeed a bug which is caused by the combination of `tick align=outside` with `extra ticks`. There the `major tick length` is taken into account "two times to much". First from the normal `major tick length` and second from the `major tick length` of the `extra y ticks`.

Please have a look at the comments in the code for more details an how to prevent/undo the additional shift. (In blue you see "your result" *with* the additional shift, in black the "correct" `ylabel` positioning.)

(I reported this to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/173/).)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat' level or higher to use the advanced positioning of the
    % axis labels
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        % give the tick length as variables, to be able to calculate a bit
        % in the `axis' options, where you cannot call them with
        %`\pgfkeysvalueof', because they are not evaluated there at this
        % point in time
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MajorTickLength}{0.20cm}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ExtraMajorTickLength}{0.15cm}
%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % for debugging purposes I enlarged the tick length and have drawn
%        % a point on the left, so that there is no shift in the plot when
%        % changing the values (in certain limits)
%        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MajorTickLength}{10mm}
%        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ExtraMajorTickLength}{5mm}
%        \fill (-5,0) circle (2pt);
%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{axis}[
        footnotesize,
        width=12.5cm,
        height=9.45817cm,
        xlabel={Absorption Energy ($\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$)},
        ylabel={Fluorescence Energy ($\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$)},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % this gives you the "correct" ylabel positioning
        % (to see that this is really the "right" position, comment the
        %  `ylabel style' and the `extra y ticks' line. Watch the updating
        %  PDF where you will not see a jump of the ylabel.)
        ylabel style={
            yshift=-\MajorTickLength - \ExtraMajorTickLength,
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        extra y ticks={37425,37435,37445,37455,37465,37475,37485,37495,37505,37515,37525},
        extra tick style={
            major tick length=\ExtraMajorTickLength,   % <-- (this adds a shift as well)
            xticklabels={},
            yticklabels={},
        },
        xtick distance=5,
        ytick distance=10,
        minor y tick num=9,
        scale only axis=true,
        enlargelimits=false,
        axis on top,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        tick align=outside,         % <-- this causes the shift
        major tick length=\MajorTickLength,
        tick style={black},
        scaled ticks=false,
        ticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                1000 sep={\thinspace},
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % for debugging purposes only to be able to see TikZ stuff outside
        % the plot area
        clip mode=individual,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot graphics [
            xmin=37537.2353,
            xmax=37566.88252,
            ymin=37424.51271,
            ymax=37526.87033,
%            % (to fully fill the plot area don't use `keepaspectratio')
%            includegraphics={keepaspectratio}
        ] {example-image};

        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % for debugging purposes only to find out, what is happening with
        % the ylabel positioning
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xshift}{
                % offset when ticks are inside (roughly estimated)
                -7ex
                % additional offset when ticks are outside
                - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}
                % additional offset of extra ticks
                - (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length} + \ExtraMajorTickLength)
            }
        \node [rotate=90,anchor=south,text=blue,font=\small]
            (dot) at ([xshift=\xshift]rel axis cs:0,0.5)
                {Fluorescence Energy ($\mathrm{cm}^{-1})$};
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you for explaining the issue so thoroughly. For comparison purposes it may also help to include a copy of my code with just the fix applied, as opposed to all the additional changes you made. I appreciate that my code probably contains the sort of stylistic ugliness that comes with beginner code, even if it did work, but by fixing this as well it obscured your solution and made it very difficult to determine exactly what the fix was. Eventually I was able to determine that a simplified variant of your solution consisted of simply adding ````ylabel style={yshift=-0.35cm},```` to the axis.

Comment: @Ulysses, sorry if it was a bit confusing. I thought it would be kind of obvious that the block with the comment 'this gives you the "correct" ylabel positioning' is what you are searching for, for which in addition you need the definitions of the length variables. And blocks starting with the comment 'for debugging purposes' can savely be deleted.

Comment: @Ulysses, you are right, your solution also gives the right result, but the "downside" compared to my solution is, that you have to adjust the `yshift` value manually, if you change one of the `major tick length`.

Comment: It was obvious I needed that line, but not obvious how that tied in with the rest of the code, and therefore how much else I needed, especially since you removed or rewrote a lot of the other styling I had applied to my graph. And while it's true that explicitly defining the yshift is a less general solution I felt this was more suitable for my situation as the tick length is consistent throughout my entire document so there's no need to recalculate it every time. If necessary it can always be amended by a comment with the formula, as a reminder to change the value if tick length ever changes.

Comment: Honestly, I think I just need a badge that says "I'm a beginner! Use small words." :P

Comment: @Ulysses, oh no. Your solution is perfectly fine. Especially if you add your mentioned comment to change that value if you change one of the tick length.