# pgfplots: Dancing 'ylabel' when Using 'extra y ticks' / Unexpected Behaviour [Follow Up Question]

Tags: pgfplots

- Follow up question to [pgfplots: Dancing ylabel when Using '\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}' and 'extra y ticks'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375150).
- **Problem** is, if I add an `extra y tick` then the `y label` is shifted although it is not necessary at all (in my opinion).
- I try to make it very clear by adding an `extra y tick` that has the same size than the normal `y ticks`.
- In my opinion, this may be a **bug**.

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % <-- Causes dancing y label when adding  'extra y ticks'

\pgfplotsset{myDefaultStyle/.style = 
    {
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    ylabel = y Label,
    xlabel = x Label,   
    grid = major,
    }}

\begin{document}

% ######### Plot #########
% ########################
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        myDefaultStyle,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 32,
        ymin = 24.5,
        ymax = 30.1,        
        xtick = {0,10,20,30},   
        ytick = {25,26,30},     
    ]
    % Plots 
    \addplot[domain=0:10,red]{x^2};     
    %   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% ######### Plot #########
% ########################
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        myDefaultStyle,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 32,
        ymin = 24.5,
        ymax = 30.1,        
        xtick = {0,10,20,30},   
        ytick = {25,26,30},     
        extra y ticks={25.5}, % <-- Added
    ]
    % Plots     
    \addplot[domain=0:10,red]{x^2}; 
    %
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Bug reports should of course go to https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. Actually, I have trouble logging in at the moment. Somehow my login data in invalid and I tried to do the `forget your password?` thing (no email so far). Would you also consider it a bug? Maybe you can copy and paste the code to sf.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372894/43317 and https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/173/